# Clicking Qt SoftwareInputPanel should restore focus to Target Dialog/Widget

Tags: qt

I've created a Qt software input panel (SIP) following the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-inputpanel.html) and it works very well. Unfortunately clicking the SIP does not restore focus to either widget when both dialogs lose focus. To summarize, when I:

1. click outside the SIP and target dialog/window, understandably, both widgets lose focus (even although *both are configured to be on top of other dialogs*)
2. subsequently click on the SIP neither widget gains focus.

We find this behaviour a bit odd and suspect so will our users. Is there a way to restore focus to the target dialog by clicking on the SIP, when both widgets lose focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Use `QApplication::setActiveWindow()` like so:

```
void KeyboardPanel::buttonClicked( QWidget *widget )
{   
    if( m_lostFocus )
    {
        QWidget* parentWidget = m_lastFocusedWidget->parentWidget();
        if( parentWidget ) QApplication::setActiveWindow( parentWidget );
    }
}
```